# How to install a jquery plugin in DotNetNuke?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I need to figure out how to install any new jQuery plugin into DotNetNuke (DNN)

I'm pretty good with jQuery and I know how to reference the source files etc.

What I need to figure out is where in the code to include the `<script>` tag to include the new plugin.

Currently what I'm doing is include the plugin script/CSS tags inside the HTML module of any given page.

I want to include the js/cs in the header or footer of files.

Comment: Gosh, there is actually documentation for that - http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/jQuery.aspx

Comment: That documentation is actually useless, it doesn't specify how to add new plugins, rather just the bundled ones.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options. With DNN 6.x or greater you generally should use the Client Resource Management API to Register the files. It's actually very easy as you just need to register a control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
```

And then include the specific file:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="jquery.cycle.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

We generally do this through the skin as we do custom skins for most of our sites or, if we're building a custom module that needs the plugin we'll do it in the appropriate ascx file for the module.

If you only need the plugin on a particular page and it's not for a particular module, the best place to add it is through the Page Settings -> Advanced -> Page Header Tags.

You can learn more here:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx